# Spring security authorization not working though the roles provided correctly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/dms**").access("hasAnyRole('admin','dms')");
```

user should have either admin or dms role to navigate to that page.
And i logged in as admin.

from logs i can see the roles matching correctly (database role and logged in user role)

```
Granted Authorities: admin
```

but still i can see access denied. any clue?
the full log here

```
2016-11-10 16:41:46 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:157 - Checking match of 
request : '/dms.jsp'; against '/dms**'
2016-11-10 16:41:46 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:219 - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /dms.jsp; Attributes: [hasAnyRole('admin','dms')]
2016-11-10 16:41:46 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:348 - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@9546: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@586034f: Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: admin; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff6a82: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: LVXYO0lvcLRvJFcH9pJO_kO2R5B7ha4LLm3DwZ7m; Granted Authorities: admin
2016-11-10 16:41:46 DEBUG AffirmativeBased:66 - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@7ade02ad, returned: -1
2016-11-10 16:41:46 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:186 - Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84)
```

Answer (score 1):

just prefixed 'ROLE_' to the available roles solved the issue.
Not sure why spring is not allowing own roles